# cProfile reports almost all time spent in <string>:1(<lambda>)

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I'm profiling some code, and cProfile reports that almost all the time is spent in `<string>:1(<lambda>)`. What does that mean?
Here's the output of cProfile:

```
10182 function calls in 191.365 seconds
Ordered by: standard name
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   727  187.331    0.258  187.331    0.258 <string>:1(<lambda>)
     1    0.000    0.000  191.365  191.365 <string>:1(<module>)
   727    0.791    0.001    0.837    0.001 function_base.py:822(gradient)
   727    0.003    0.000    0.031    0.000 numeric.py:65(zeros_like)
     1    0.000    0.000  191.365  191.365 ode.py:316(integrate)
     1    2.447    2.447  191.365  191.365 ode.py:685(run)
  1454    0.376    0.000    1.213    0.001 useful.py:117(q_powers_opr)
   727    0.296    0.000  188.918    0.260 useful.py:95(dWave)
  1454    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {len}
   727    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   727    0.013    0.000    0.013    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   727    0.024    0.000    0.024    0.000 {method 'fill' of 'numpy.ndarray'objects}
   727    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.empty_like} 
   727    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {range}
   727    0.078    0.000    1.291    0.002 {sum}
```

Here's the profiling code:

```
import useful
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import cProfile
u=sp.Symbol('u')
q=sp.Symbol('q')
x_0=sp.Symbol('x_0')
p_0=sp.Symbol('p_0')
w=sp.Symbol('w')
L_u=sp.Lambda(u,u**4/4-5*u**2/2)
V_q=sp.Lambda(q,10*q)
sys=useful.system(L_u)
pAxis=np.linspace(-60+0j,60,10000)
pWave=useful.numpify(useful.gaussian_wavefunction.subs({x_0:5,p_0:0,w:1}))(pAxis)
pWave_t=sys.time_evolve(pWave,pAxis,V_q)
print "Starting Integration"
cProfile.run("pWave2=pWave_t.integrate(0.2)")
```

And here's useful.py, which actually does everything:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import functools
from scipy import integrate
from itertools import *
u=sp.Symbol('u')
q=sp.Symbol('q')
p=sp.Symbol('p')
w=sp.Symbol('w')
x_0=sp.Symbol('x_0')
p_0=sp.Symbol('p_0')
hStep=sp.Lambda(p,(1+sp.sign(p))/2)
gaussian_wavefunction=sp.Lambda(p,(2*sp.pi*w**2)**(-sp.Rational(1,4))*\
    sp.exp(-sp.I*x_0*p)*sp.exp(-(p-p_0)**2/(4*w**2)))
class system:
    def __init__(self,K_u):
        """
        This function accepts a definition of kinetic energy in terms of
        velocity (u). Lagrangeans with cross terms between u and q are at the
        moment outside the scope of this program; this may change.
        """
        #This file will use the convention {function}_{input variables}
        #I can't figure out how to allow parameterization of the lagrangean,
        #   so I won't for now.
        self.p_u=sp.Lambda(u,sp.diff(K_u(u),u))
        u_crit=sp.solve(sp.diff(self.p_u(u),u))
        self.p_crit=map(self.p_u,u_crit)
        n_p_crit=sorted([complex(sp.N(p_crit))
            for p_crit in self.p_crit],key=lambda x: x.real)
        #print n_p_crit
        self.H_u=sp.Lambda(u,sp.expand(self.p_u(u)*u-K_u(u)))
        self.u_p=[sp.Lambda(p,u_p_i) for u_p_i in sp.solve(self.p_u(u)-p,u)]
        #This will fail horribly if there is only one critical point;
        #   really you shouldn't be using it in that case, though, so..
        test_points=[2*n_p_crit[0]-n_p_crit[1]] #Left of the leftmost point
        test_points+=[(p_1+p_2)/2 for (p_1,p_2) in
            izip(n_p_crit[:-1],n_p_crit[1:])] #average of every pair of points
        test_points+=[2*n_p_crit[-1]-n_p_crit[-2]]#Right of the rightmost point
        def slopeSign(f):
            #Given a symbolic function f, returns a numerical function over the
            #   same domain, which gives the sign of the slope of f.
            def out(x):
                deriv=sp.diff(f(p),p).subs(p,x)#Note this is still sympified
                return int(np.sign(complex(deriv).real))
            return out
        #Note that the below is a generator. A streight list will not close
        #   arround u_p_i, and they'll all reference the last one. Annoying,
        #   although a generator is better for this job anyway.
        n_orientation_p=(slopeSign(u_p_i) for u_p_i in self.u_p)
        orientation=[[n_orientation_p_i(point)
            for point in test_points] for n_orientation_p_i in n_orientation_p]
        #The following determines the validity of u(p) in each region for each
        #   velocity functuion
        valid=[[-0.0001<complex(u_p_i(point)).imag<0.0001
            for point in test_points] for u_p_i in self.u_p ]
        step=[sp.Lambda(p,hStep(n_p_crit[0]-p))]
        step+=[sp.Lambda(p,hStep(p-p_1)*hStep(p_2-p))
            for (p_1,p_2) in izip(n_p_crit[:-1],n_p_crit[1:])]
        step+=[sp.Lambda(p,hStep(p-n_p_crit[-1]))]
        #The effective factors are functions of p, valued at -1,0,or 1, that
        #   are multiplied by the various possible functions of p based on
        #   functions of u (see H_eff_p for example)
        def signedSteps(sign,nonzero):
            for (step_i,sign_i,nonzero_i) in izip(step,sign,nonzero):
                yield step_i(p)*sign_i*int(nonzero_i)
        def eff_factor(orientation_i,valid_i):
            return sp.Lambda(p,sum(signedSteps(orientation_i,valid_i)))
        self.eff_factors_p=[eff_factor(orientation_i,valid_i)
                for (orientation_i,valid_i) in izip(orientation,valid)]
        self.H_eff_p=self.effective_function(self.H_u)
        #a system will have the following:
        #p_u,H_u,u_p,H_p,eff_factors_p,H_eff_p
    def effective_function(self,f_u):
        f_p=[sp.Lambda(p,sp.expand(f_u(u_p_i(p)))) for u_p_i in self.u_p]
        #The above is a list of functions in terms of p.
        return sp.Lambda(p,sum(f_p_i(p)*eff_factors_p_i(p)\
            for (f_p_i,eff_factors_p_i) in izip(f_p,self.eff_factors_p)))
    def time_evolve(self,pWave,pAxis,V_q=0):
        H_eff_p_n=numpify(self.H_eff_p)
        if V_q==0:
            return pWave*np.exp(-(0+1j)*t*H_eff_p_n(pAxis))
        else:
            try:
                #[-2::-1] gives the coeffs in order q^1,q^2,q^3...
                V_q_coeffs=V_q(q).as_poly().all_coeffs()[-2::-1]
                V_q_coeffs=map(complex,V_q_coeffs)#De-sympifies the coeffs
            except TypeError, te:#Not everything is a polynomial...
                print "Nonpolynomial potentials are not supported"
                raise
            if (np.abs(np.diff(pAxis,2))<0.0001).all():
                spacing=pAxis[1]-pAxis[0]
            else:
                spacing=np.gradient(pAxis)
            print spacing
            def dWave(t,pWave,pAxis):
                dWave=-(0+1j)*H_eff_p_n(pAxis)*pWave
                dWave+=-(0+1j)*sum(q_powers_opr(pWave,V_q_coeffs,spacing))
                """
            def dWave(pWave,H_eff_p_n,V_q_coeffs,pAxis,spacing):
                dWave=np.empty_like(pWave)
                dWave[1::2]=-H_eff_p_n(pAxis)*pWave[::2]
                dWave[::2]=H_eff_p_n(pAxis)*pWave[1::2]
                vWave=sum(q_powers_opr(pWave,V_q_coeffs,spacing))
                dWave[1::2]=-vWave[::2]
                dWave[::2]=vWave[1::2]
                del vWave
                """
                return dWave
            ode=integrate.ode(dWave)
            ode.set_integrator('zvode')
            ode.set_f_params(pAxis)
            ode.set_initial_value(pWave)
            #ode.set_f_params(H_eff_p_n,V_q_coeffs,pAxis,spacing)
            return ode
            #integrate.odeint(dWave,pWave,[0,t],
            #    args=(H_eff_p_n,V_q_coeffs,spacing))
def q_powers_opr(wave,coeffs,spacing):
    #nextWave=np.empty_like(wave)
    for c in coeffs:
        yield c*(0+1j)*np.gradient(wave)/spacing
        """
        nextWave[1::2]=c*np.gradient(wave[::2])/spacing
        nextWave[::2]=-c*np.gradient(wave[1::2])/spacing
        wave=nextWave
        """
def numpify(func):
    try:
        return map(numpify,func)
    except TypeError, te:#If there is only one function
        return sp.lambdify(func.variables,func(*func.variables),"numpy")
def niceIfft(pAxis,pWave):
    pRange=pAxis[-1]-pAxis[0]
    p0=pAxis[0]
    length=np.size(pAxis)
    xRange=2*np.pi*length/pRange
    xAxis=np.linspace(-xRange/2,xRange/2,length)
    iAxis=np.arange(length)
    xWave=(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*pRange*np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(pWave))*
        np.exp(2*np.pi*(0+1j)*(-p0)/pRange*iAxis))
    return (xAxis,xWave)
```

Comment: read the next few lines in the report: almost all time is spent in `def dWave(t,pWave,pAxis)`

Comment: True, but it doesn't explain what part of dWave is slow. Do I just need to profile dWave independently to get the details of what's happening inside it?

Comment: After profiling dWave, I get similarly useless results. All the time in dWave is spent in `<string>:1(<lambda>)`.

Comment: cProfile shows times for functions e.g., there is the result for `sum()`

Comment: I found where dWave is spending most of its time: It's on `H_eff_p_n(pAxis)`. When I profile just that line, the profiler gives the same `<string>:1(<lambda>)`. I'm not posting this as an answer, because I would still be very interested to find out how I could have found this if dWave was longer (without binary searching through the code to isolate out the slow part).

Comment: Does sympy construct and run a lot of lambda funcs (using 'compile' or similar) and you are seeing the total time of all those funcs reported together?

Comment: Looks like it was just the one. The new cProfile (after precomputing H_eff_p_n(pAxis) ) is dominated by the ode solver and the gradient function, with no lambdas at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `numpify` function. It's used to create `H_eff_p_n`, which is the only function called by `dWave` that isn't explicitly named in the output. I don't know how `lambdify` works, but it must, in some way or another, create a lambda function by `exec`ing a string. And of course, a `lambda` is anonymous!

```
>>> (lambda x: x).func_name
'<lambda>'
```

I just saw your comment above; a simple workaround is to simply use `def`. As in...

```
H_eff_p_n_lambda=numpify(self.H_eff_p)
def H_eff_p_n(*args, **kwargs):
    return H_eff_p_n_lambda(*args, **kwargs)
```

This won't perform as well, but it will at least make it clear (via `cumtime`) which lambda is being slow. I thought modifying the `__name__` or `func_name` attribute might help, but it didn't work for me.

Looking more closely at the source of `profile` (which I assume does roughly the same thing as `cProfile` here), it seems that the function name that `profile` uses comes not from `func.func_name`, but rather from [`func.func_code.co_name`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/profile.py#l277), which is read only! So giving a lambda a name for profiling purposes might be hard.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Turns out I can precompute that value and it cuts down execution time by a factor of 60.